# Intento cambiar de versión node con nvm

Tags: nodejs

Al intentar cambiar la versión con nvm con el comando: nvm use 12.19.0

Recibo el mensaje ahora usando v12.19.0

Pongo el comando: node --version

v14.17.3

Pongo: nvm list

- 14.17.3 (Currently using 64-bit executable)

  12.19.0

  8.17.0

Se pueden descargar versiones pero sólo queda activa la 14.17.3

Quiero usar la versión 12.19.0

Comment: Solucionado tuve que desinstalar el nvm y volverlo a instalar con una versión de node instalada.

Comment: Me esta ocurriendo lo mismo no entiendo aun porque no cambia, yo trate eliminando la carpeta de node de mi computador, pero aun asi cuando hago nvm use 14.0.0 (este es mi caso), aun asi no me cambia sino que me instala la 18.

Answer (score 0):

Es con nvm use "version"
(En "version" pon la versión que quieres usar, por ejemplo 16.6.2)

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/310104)

Answer (score 0):

Renombra "C:\Program Files\nodejs" a "C:\Program Files\nodejsx",
Después desde un cmd con permiso de admin corre "nvm use v12.19.0" o la versión que quieras.
Fue la solución que encontré

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).